# How to count records by substring in one of fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
  company_name TEXT,
  product_name TEXT
);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES("first_company|Live", "some_product");
INSERT INTO foo VALUES("first_company|Demo", "some_product");
INSERT INTO foo VALUES("second_company|Live", "another_product");
INSERT INTO foo VALUES("third_company|Demo", "another_product");
```

I need to count products' count on live and demo servers, so I tried the following query to count live servers at first:

```
SELECT product_name, COUNT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name, '|', 1) LIKE '%Live%') AS count
FROM `foo` GROUP BY product_name ORDER BY count DESC;
```

But it gives me the following result:

```
product_name    count
some_product    2
another_product 2
```

I expected to see count == 1 for both products because each of them was installed on one live server only.

What am I doing wrong? How to achieve such behavior?

Comment: What you're doing wrong? Storing Live/Demo in the same column as the company name is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break your query down a bit. GEt rid of the Group and the count and you'll see what's going on:

```
SELECT product_name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name, '|', 1) like '%Live%'  AS count
FROM `foo`  ORDER BY count DESC;
```

returns

```
another_product 0
some_product    0
some_product    0
another_product 0
```

Look at why this is:

```
SELECT product_name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(company_name, '|', 1)  AS count
FROM `foo`  ORDER BY count DESC;


another_product third_company
another_product second_company
some_product    first_company
some_product    first_company
```

Try instead:

```
SELECT product_name, company_name like '%Live%'  AS count
FROM `foo`  ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Which returns:

```
some_product    1
another_product 1
another_product 0
some_product    0
```

So what you actually want to run is:

```
SELECT product_name, count(company_name like '%Live%')>0  AS count
FROM `foo`
group by product_name
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Which returns what you want.

Your issue was that you were doing the check, but then counting ALL results, not just where the criteria was matched.

Really a better way to do this, and which would  make the count function operation more clear is like this:

```
SELECT product_name, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM `foo`
where company_name LIKE '%Live%' 
 GROUP BY product_name ORDER BY count DESC;
```

So count(*) selects how many records there are
you're grouping by product name, so you'll get one row for each product name, and count counts how many records there are with that product name.

The WHERE filter means you're only getting records where company_name like '%Live%' (which is what your question is looking for).

So now, count(*) will show how many records there are for each product_name, satisfying that criterion.

Say you wanted the count of each product for live and demo rows. I've added some rows to the table to demonstrate this. `foo` now looks like this:

third_company|Demo  another_product
first_company|Live  some_product
first_company|Demo  some_product
second_company|Live another_product
fourth_company|Demo another_product
fourth_company|Demo a_third_product

so if you have a column in your query

```
company_name like '%Live%'
```

it will return 0 if it's not like Live, 1 if it is. Now, grouping by product name, what you want is to SUM that column, so you get the number of rows where that is true:

```
SELECT 
    product_name, 
    sum(company_name like '%Live%')  AS count_live,
    sum(company_name like '%Demo%')  AS count_demo
FROM `foo` group by product_name
;
```

Which returns:

```
another_product 1   2
some_product    1   1
a_third_product 0   1
```

Seems you wanted sum all along!

Comment: I just noticed that I tried to find `Live` word in the part **before** the pipe character ('|'), not after it

Comment: You'd still need to adjust what you're COUNT()ing.

Comment: I still don't really understand how `COUNT` works then

Comment: Can I count the demo and live installations in the same query?

Comment: I understand what you were trying to do now, will edit again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to count other records as well (those that doesn't contain "Live" nor "Demo" substrings)

Comment: You would use the same pattern, but with a more complicated boolean, i.e.  "sum(company_name not like '%Live%' and company_name not like '%Demo%') as count_other"

Comment: How does it work? Is `GROUP BY` applied earlier than `SUM`, so it can sum all these 0's and 1's?

Comment: sum is applied after the group by. The elements of the group are handed to the sum function.

Comment: Also the other answer to this question addresses another concern, you should really split 'x_company|Live' into two seperate columns, this would make this much easier

Comment: What do you mean by split? `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function?

Comment: Plus one for the detailed explanation of why COUNT() isn't working as OP expected.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store two pieces of information in the same field! Otherwise you'll run into readability, query complication and performance issues faster than you can say 'bottleneck'.

You can split these out quite easily, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
  company_name TEXT,
  product_name TEXT,
  status TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES("first_company", "some_product", 1);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES("first_company", "some_product", 0);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES("second_company", "another_product", 1);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES("third_company", "another_product", 0);
```

Then, queries become simpler:

```
  SELECT product_name, SUM(status) AS live_count
    FROM `foo` 
GROUP BY product_name 
ORDER BY live_count DESC;
```

You should probably be storing your companies and products in different tables too and referencing these by an id.. but that's a whole new kettle of fun.

Comment: This table already exists. I don't know why the author decided to store this information in the same field

Comment: @FrozenHeart My advice would be: If you can, change the structure. If you can't, contact the author or someone who can and change the structure! If you need 'live' or 'demo' concatted on to the name, you can do this in the application layer :)